# angularJS failed to load module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, kinvey

Is there anyone know why I got the following issue:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=helloKinveyApp&p1=E…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)angular.min.js:6 (anonymous function)angular.min.js:36 (anonymous function)angular.min.js:7 rangular.min.js:35 gangular.min.js:38 Obangular.min.js:17 dangular.min.js:18 scangular.min.js:16 Hdangular.min.js:249 (anonymous function)angular.min.js:163 aangular.min.js:32 c

```
var app = angular.module("helloKinveyApp", ["ngRoute", "kinvey"]);

app.run(["$kinvey", function($kinvey) {
    var promise = $kinvey.init({
       appKey: clientParams.appKey
        , appSecret: clientParams.appSecret
    });

    promise.then(function() {
        console.log("Kinvey init with success");
    }, function(errorCallback) {
        console.log("Kinvey init with error: " + JSON.stringify(errorCallback));
    });
}]);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="helloKinveyApp">
    <head>
        <title>Hello Kinvey Lesson 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-view="" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://da189i1jfloii.cloudfront.net/js/kinvey-angular-1.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use non-minified version of angular, you would get more details about the issue

Comment: In what section of your application is the following line located `var app = angular.module("helloKinveyApp", ["ngRoute", "kinvey"]);`?

Comment: And what is _jQuery_ tag doing here?

Comment: may be you are not including the js file in which module is defined?

Comment: Put kinvey.js load above the angular.js file load

Comment: Below is the detail of exception
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module helloKinveyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'helloKinveyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @BenDiamant, why should kinvey be above angular? His app module definition rather should be below both angular and kinvey.

Answer (score 0):

If your code was structured in a manner similar as below, it SHOULD work (i.e. you should get a module load error):

```
...
<body>
    ...
    <div data-ng-view="" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://da189i1jfloii.cloudfront.net/js/kinvey-angular-1.1.4.min.js">
    </script>
    ...
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("helloKinveyApp", ["ngRoute", "kinvey"]);

        app.run(["$kinvey", function($kinvey) {
            var promise = $kinvey.init({
               appKey: clientParams.appKey,
               appSecret: clientParams.appSecret
            });

            promise.then(function() {
                console.log("Kinvey init with success");
            }, function(errorCallback) {
                console.log("Kinvey init with error: " + JSON.stringify(errorCallback));
            });
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I forgot to reference to app.js in index.html

Comment: so that's it. And it should be below both angular and kinvey since it's dependent on them both. Put at the last, and your problems should be solved.

Comment: Don't forget to select this as the answer if it helped fix your problem.